# Direct fetch or fetch,store,render in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am making a social site in react. When current user opens profile of other user, then should I directly fetch the user details from server to component or first push it store and then render it in the component ?? 
 If I directly fetch the userdata in componentWillMount and save it to local state to manage the client side interection like 'follow the user' , will it be fine?

Answer (score 1):

When some data is needed we dispatch `fetch-action`, some middleware listen for it and make API call that will be transformed into `fetch-success` or `fetch-error`.

[Some example](https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3).

As middleware to listen to some action:
easy to use, hard to test - [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

advanced - [redux-observables](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable), [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga)

Answer (score 0):

Sujoy, it would have been great, if you would have shared what you tried thus far. Since you did not provide any code that I could assist you to refactor, this is my answer:

This would be how you would write your action creator, I used an api from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com to fetch some fake users:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchUsers() {
  const request = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');

  return (dispatch) => {
    request.then(({data}) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_PROFILES', payload: data });
    });
  };
}
```

In order to understand what is going on above and have it work correctly, you need to use `redux-thunk` and understand why you are using it.

The reason why, is because vanilla Redux expects for you to return an action, which is a plan JavaScript object. Redux Thunk on the other hand, enables one other return type and that is just a plain JavaScript function.

So only with Redux Thunk are you able to return a plain JavaScript function as you see above in the code example I provided.

You will see that the first argument to this function is the `dispatch` method. `dispatch` acts as a pipeline from getting your data down to your reducers, but with Redux Thunk, its more in your control, more manual and used for asynchronous operations such as what you are describing.

So the code above is waiting for the request to resolve with some amount of data and its not until the request has resolved will it dispatch the action and take note that is also using a package called `axios`, highly recommended for http requests.

For the `App.js` file, it would look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }

  renderUser({id, name, email}) {
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={id}>
        <span className="label pull-xs-right">
          <a href={email}>{email}</a>
        </span>
        {name}
      </li>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Email Directory</h4>
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.props.users.map(this.renderUser)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect((state => state), actions)(App);
```

What the above does is fetch a list of users and then renders a single `li` for each user. In this case, I am showing the users `{email}` and `{name}`. So `fetchUsers()` is the action creator and you can see inside of `componentWillMount()` which I believe is what you were asking about as well. So this should work for you.